# Android Studio drawable selector unknown issue

Tags: android, xml, button, drawable

I seem to have a problem that I just do not know how to solve with Android Studio. The code worked find on Eclipse and the weird thing is that it also works on the Design preview window of Android Studio, but does not work when I execute the application on any real device.
The problem I'm having is with the drawable folder where I have a selector xml and a shape xml file. In my layout, I set the background of the button to the selector xml file. I noticed a very annoying red circle with an exclamation mark in the selector xml file where I specify the drawable to be the shape xml file. It doesn't state what the problem is, if any. It looks just like the following picture: 

[image]

The Design preview window shows the button as specified in the drawable xml files:
[image]

Here is the code for my files:

bshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FFAA33"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

button.xml (selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Normal state of button -->
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bshape" />

</selector>
```

myLayout (RelativeLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Button Test"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've made sure the xml files have the .xml extension. I've noticed several posts regarding missing the extension in the xml file.
This is really driving me nuts. I've spent about 3 hours attempting to solve this problem and I just don't know what it could be. Any help is extremely appreciated. Thank you in advanced!

Edit:
Below is a picture of all the files listed in my project.
[image]

Comment: Did you try building the app?

Comment: Yes I did. I cleaned the project, removed generated files, rebuild project and the problem still persist.

Comment: If you're on a windows machine or Linux. Try moving your cursor to bshape and press ALT+Enter it will give you suggestions on how to fix it

Comment: I'm using windows and I should also state that my app's minimum SDK is 15 and targetting 23.
When I press ALT+Enter, I get a menu that says:  "Override Resource in Other Configuration..."

Comment: Try overriding and see which file it does override and you can then see where the problem lies.

Comment: All I see is the "Select Resource Directory" which lists a set of available qualifiers for me to chose. Here is a few:
Country Code,
Network Code,
Locale,
Layout Direction,
Smallest Screen Width,
....

Comment: Which drawable folders are you using in your app? As a rule of thumb, all the xml drawables are usually placed in the drawable folder, where as the pngs or jpegs are place in the other folders for different screen density.

Comment: Please take a look at my latest edit on the question. I took a screenshot of the project tree and you can see that I have one drawable folder and I'm using mipmap folders for the icons. I'm not using images for background buttons or anything like that. I just want to use solid colors for buttons and border colors as well. Nothing special.

Comment: everything seems okay. Try deleting the file and recreating it.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I've done that several times. Deleted the folder from Android Studio, created it again. Created xml files from scratch again. Doesn't work. Deleted files and created folder+xml files manually in windows explorer, then opened android studio and still same problem.

Comment: I just tried another phone and now I'm getting a build error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. <path>\button.xml: Error: In DataSet 'main', no data file for changedFile. This is an internal error in the incremental builds code; to work around it, try doing a full clean build.

Comment: I am sorry, i am unable to figure out the problem. But one last suggestion would be after reading this error. Try giving both the files a different name and clean build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to thank Eric for his attempt at providing a solution to my problem. Thank you very much Eric!

It seems to be working, however the red circle with the exclamation point still shows in the button.xml selector file.

This is what I did, I used the Design view to select the button and under the Properties pane, I clicked on background ... button and the Resources window came up. I selected the Project tab, then I searched for Drawables->button and clicked OK.

I performed a 'Clean Project' by going to Build->Clean Project. Then I build the project by executing Build->Rebuild Project in the Menu bar.

Now it seems to be working as expected. I believe this could very well be a bug in Android Studio. There goes 4hrs of my life I will never get back :)

Comment: That's great! Congrats!